# My site displayed deceptive site ahead message

Tags: php, web

I am a beginner in web development. I am developing a website. From few days my site is not gonna run in good way. When i write down the URL of site and hit enter key. Than a window is displayed.

[image]

I searched it on google. But i'm failed to sort out this. 
I don't understand how to remove it. Please any one can help me how i can sort out this. 
Thanks

Comment: go to https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=YourDomain.com and you know why the error happens

Comment: It says. Some pages on abc.com contain deceptive content right now. so how can i identify that pages?

Answer (score 1):

Add your site to google webmasters and check which urls / pages are creating errors under security issues. Simply delete / fix that files and submit review request to google.

More info, http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-this-site-ahead-contains-harmful-programs-error-in-wordpress/